# How to count the values in an array and get the value if its equal to a number PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 1
  2 => 2
]
```

I want to count how many times a number is equal in the array and if the count of equal numbers is 2 push the value into an other array.

so:

in this case 1 is equal 2 times, so i want to push 1 into an array.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you out, here we are using `array_count_values` function for counting the values of an array.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784335)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array=array(
    1,
    1,
    2
);
$result=array();
foreach(array_count_values($array) as $key => $value)
{
    if($value==2)//checking whether the count of number is equal to 2
    {
        $result[]=$key;//pushing value in array
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This helped me, i will approve your answer when i can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this:

```
$tempArr = $secondArr = array();
foreach($firstArr as $value) {
   if(in_array($value,$tempArr)) {
       $secondArr[] = $value;
   }
   $tempArr[] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
function getMyArray($input_arr, $threshold){
    $final_arr = [];
    $arr_counts = array_count_values($input_arr);
    foreach( $arr_counts as $key => $value ){
        if ( $value == $threshold ){
            $final_arr[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $final_arr;
}
```

Pass your input array and your cutoff mark!

Answer (score 1):

-Here is the simplest Solution.

```
$new_array = array();
$exist_array = array(1,1,2);
  foreach(array_count_values($exist_array) as $k=>$v){
    if($v == 2)
      $new_array[] = $k;
   }

  print_r($new_array);
```